# How can I make an ostream reference an ofstream? (C++)

Tags: c++, reference, ofstream, ostream

I'm trying to make a simple logger class, and I want the ability to either log to either a generic `ostream` (`cout`/`cerr`) or a file.  The design I have in mind is to allow the constructor to either take an `ostream&` or a filename, and in the latter case create an `ofstream&` and assign that to the class' private `ostream&` like so:

```
class Log {
private:
    std::ostream& os;
public:
    Log(std::ostream& os = std::cout): os(os) { }
    Log(std::string filename) {
        std::ofstream ofs(filename);
        if (!ofs.is_open())
            // do errorry things
        os = ofs;
    }
};
```

Doing such gives me an error that `ofstream`'s assignment operator is private.  Looking over that again, it occurred to me that making a reference to a local object probably wouldn't work, and making `os` a pointer to an `ostream` and declaring and deleting it on the heap worked with the `ofstream` case, though not with the `ostream` case, where the `ostream` already exists and is just being referenced by `os` (because the only place to delete `os` would be in the constructor, and I don't know of a way to determine whether or not `os` is pointing to an `ofstream` created on the heap or not).

So how can I make this work, i.e. make `os` reference an `ofstream` initialized with a filename in the constructor?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For one thing, you can't rebind references once they're created, you can only initialise them. You might think you could do this:

```
Log(std::string filename) : os(std::ofstream(filename)) {
    if (!os.is_open())
        // do errorry things
}
```

But that's no good because you are making `os` refer to a temporary variable.

When you need a reference that has to be *optional*, that is, it needs to refer to something sometimes and not other times, what you really need is a *pointer*:

```
class Log {
private:
    std::ostream* os;
    bool dynamic;
public:
    Log(std::ostream& os = std::cout): os(&os), dynamic(false) { }
    Log(std::string filename) : dynamic(true) {
        std::ofstream* ofs = new std::ofstream(filename);

        if (!ofs->is_open())
            // do errorry things and deallocate ofs if necessary

        os = ofs;
    }

    ~Log() { if (dynamic) delete os; }
};
```

The above example is just to show you what is going on, but you probably will want to manage it with a smart pointer. As Ben Voigt points out, there are a lot of gotchas that will cause unforeseen and undesired behaviour in your program; for example, when you try to make a copy of the above class, it will hit the fan. Here is an example of the above using smart pointers:

```
class Log {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<std::ostream, std::function<void(std::ostream*)>> os;
public:
    Log(std::ostream& os = std::cout): os(&os, [](ostream*){}) { }

    Log(std::string filename) : os(new std::ofstream(filename), std::default_delete<std::ostream>()) {
        if (!dynamic_cast<std::ofstream&>(*os).is_open())
            // do errorry things and don't have to deallocate os
    }
};
```

The unusual `os(&os, [](ostream*){})` makes the pointer point to the given `ostream&` but do nothing when it goes out of scope; it gives it a deleter function that does nothing. You can do this without lambdas too, it's just easier for this example.

Comment: So, assuming I'm still creating the ofstream in the constructor, there really isn't any way to avoid declaring/deleting os on the heap, is there?

Comment: @Anachrome no there's no other way, because you want to create it in _one_ constructor (and not the other) but have it last after the constructor is exited. The only way to do that that I know of is to allocate it dynamically.

Comment: Ouch! Careful with the destructor! `{ Log l; }` will try to call `delete &std::cout;`! You need a flag there.

Comment: A well.  I'll manage.  And in regards to your code, wouldn't there be problems deleting in the destructor if it was created via the first constructor (and therefore wasn't dynamically alocated)?  Of course, this is all just more reason to use smart pointers, I guess.

Comment: @Anachrome yes, that is exactly right. That is also what R. Martinho Fernandes mentioned, and I have fixed it.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be better to have an internal `ofstream` object and a `ostream*` pointing to either the internal `ofstream` or an external `ostream` so that you avoid the dynamic allocation *and* remove that ugly flag?

Comment: @AndréCaron that's what Nawaz's answer did, but he deleted it for some reason. I had forgotten that `ofstream`s can be default constructed when I wrote this answer.

Comment: You should mention why a smart pointer is needed.  The example code is a complete disaster waiting to happen, since the compiler thinks its blitable and will generate a copy constructor that does.  And that's just one of many potential gotchas

Comment: Unfortunately, the deleter type is an explicit template parameter of `unique_ptr`. This means you can't use it to store deleters of different types. You need some type-erasure, either with `std::function<void(void*)>` or a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Even better may be a simple deleter functor that also carries the flag, and acts accordingly. No need for elaborated type erasure and lambdas here.

Comment: +1 if you can implement the copy constructor! Seriously, I need to be able to do `Log log(cerr); Log log2(log); log2.output("hey");`

Answer (score 10):

The simplest thing to do is just bind your reference to an `ofstream`, and make sure the `ofstream` lives as long as your object:

```
class Log
{
    std::ofstream byname;
    std::ostream& os;
public:
    Log(std::ostream& stream = std::cout) : byname(), os(stream) { }
    Log(std::string filename) : byname(filename), os(this->byname)
    {
        if (!os)
            // handle errors
    }
};
```

Exception safe, can't leak, and the compiler-generated special member functions are sane.

Comment: There's a certain beauty in the simplicity of this that's actually making me think I might end up using this instead of the above answer.  Not quite decided yet, though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the `os` in the initialize list in the constructors, just as what you did in `Log(std::ostream& os = std::cout): os_(os) { }`, because `os` is a reference, which can not be assigned after initialized.

Comment: Only if he makes `os` a reference to a const.

Comment: @jrok and then he can't write to or read from it. And even then, the `ofstream` will be destroyed at the end of the constructor.

Comment: @Seth That's right. EDIT: no, the second part is not right. The reference to a const (and the temporary with it) will be valid for the lifetime of the class object.

Comment: @jrok: No, only local variables can extend lifetime of temporaries. Member variables don't.

Comment: @Martinho. Well, I honestly didn't know that. :) Thanks.

Comment: @jrok actually if the reference is `const` then the temporary will live to the end of the constructor

Answer (score 0):

In my Log/Debug class I find it useful to create a static member variable:

```
class debug {
  public:
    ...

    // Overload operator() for printing values.
    template<class Type1>
      inline debug&
      operator()(const std::string& name1,
                 const Type1& value1)
      {
        // Prettify the name/value someway in another inline function.
        _stream << print_value(name1, value1) << std::endl;

        return *this;
      }

  private:
    ...
    static std::ostream& _stream;
};
```

And then in my debug.cc file:

```
std::ostream& debug::_stream = std::cerr;
```